# Customize Rocket Dock

Tags: rocketdock

How do I customize rocket dock so that when I point to an application or folder that is docked on rocket dock. Other Options will appear. For example, folders that is within the folder that is dragged on rocket dock. 
Or if you point to an application launcher that is in rocket dock. Rocket dock will show the applications that has shortcuts on that application launcher.

simplified: A rocket dock which is the same as the file explorer. Wherein there is a root folder that is being expanded and expanded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer: http://rocketdock.com/addon/docklets/1791

Comment: + 1, this answers the question